# Accidental NilClass in my instance variables

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, undefined, null

I am making a dating simulator. One of the first things I need is to keep track of the way characters feel about each other. In this sim, anyone can date anyone else, and there are two variables for relationship (one for love and one for friendship).

So I thought the easiest way to do this would be for each character to have a separate class that kept track of how they felt about everyone else. Below is one such sample class. I also thought that the easiest way to keep track of where points should be added was by giving each character a hash that pointed to their own variable, and then using a swap function to trade targets with the person they are speaking to.

However, I am getting an error message.

```
class HRelatStatus
  def initialize
   {@target=> @hrelat}
   @krelat =[10, 10]
   @arelat =[9, 4]
   @srelat =[13, 11]
   @jrelat =[12, 1]
   @brelat =[5, 5]
   @hrelat=[0, 0]
  end
   def dataaccess
    attr_accessor :target, :krelat, :arelat, :srelat, :jrelat, :brelat, :hrelat
  end
  def makehappy
    @target[0] = @target[0]+1  
  end  
end

hfeels=HRelatStatus.new
puts @krelat.class
puts @krelat[1]
hfeels.makehappy
puts @target[0]
```

When I try to run this, @krelat comes back as a Nil class. And when I try to run the makehappy method (or any method, really) I get the error message undefined method '[]' for nil class.

How do I stop my instance variables from being nil classes? How can I sucessfully make methods that will add to one variable in the array for a specific character? And does anyone have a better idea for how I can specify who to target?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows such poorly constructed code that the answer will be of little or no use to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying:

```
hfeels=HRelatStatus.new
puts @krelat.class
```

But there is no such thing as `@krelat` in this context. What you are after is the `krelat` instance variable inside your instance, i.e. `hfeels.krelat`.

(Of course, *that* won't work either because you've hidden your accessor generators inside an instance method.)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you actually need to do is learn how Ruby (or really, variable scope in any language) works.

`@krelat` outside of the class is totally unrelated to `@krelat` inside the class.

The `makehappy` method won't work because `{ @target => @hrelat }` doesn't do anything in Ruby (well, it creates a hash with a `nil` key pointing to a `nil` value and then discards that hash.  Ie. effectively nothing.

This code is a total mess, learn Ruby first.  Buy "Programming Ruby" and read it.